# Замена атрибута type button без отправки

Tags: jquery

Делаю форму входа на сайт. На ней две кнопки. У первой атрибут `type="submit"`, то есть при клике по ней происходит отправка, а у второй атрибут `type="button"`, при клике по ней происходит преобразование формы в регистрационную. В этот момент, помимо всего прочего, нужно присвоить атрибут `type="submit"` кнопке регистрации, чтобы при повторном клике произошла отправка.

Всё конечно меняется при первом клике, но при этом происходит отправка. Как быть?

```js
 $('.btn-register').on("click", function () {
        // меняем местами тип 
        $('.btn-login').attr('type', 'button');
        $('.btn-register').attr('type', 'submit');
    });
```

```html
   <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-inverse btn-login">Вход</button>
<button type="button" name="register" class="btn btn-register">Регистрация</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать флаг, который укажет, какая форма сейчас активна.

```
$('.btn-register').on("click", function () {
        if (isRegisterForm){
          // do something like .submit(); 
          // or close that form and etc
        }
        else{
          $('.btn-login').attr('type', 'button');
          $('.btn-register').attr('type', 'submit');
          // show the registration form
          isRegisterForm = true;
          return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Вот, хороший совет :) Где же вы раньше были - больше часа мучаюсь с этими атрибутами! Только додумался и тут вы подсказали! :) Спасибо вам большое)))

Comment: =) Рад что я смог вам помочь)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить return false вдруг поможет, но я не уверен

```js
$('.btn-register').on("click", function () {
        // меняем местами тип 
        $('.btn-login').attr('type', 'button');
        $('.btn-register').attr('type', 'submit');

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь не отправляется при первом клике. Но и не отправляется при втором хотя в хроме видно, что атрибут submit присвоен. Что бы это могло быть?)

Comment: Мб стоит отвязать событие на клик после первого нажатия ? Хотя это костыль.Лучше сделать флаг, который показывает, какая форма сейчас активна (входа или регистрации) и если 1ое- return false; , если 2ое - то ничего не делать (т.к. ожидается что кнопка уже стала сабмитом).